# Error while uploading multiple images for a product in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im receiving this error, "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given"  but with a successful upload, how can resolve it.

```
foreach ($this->attribute_values as $key=>$attribute_value) {
    $avalues = explode(",", $attribute_value);
    foreach ($avalues as $avalue) {
        $attr_value = new AttributeValue();
        $attr_value->product_attribute_id = $key;
        $attr_value->value = $avalue;
        $attr_value->product_id = $product->id;
        $attr_value->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: With `$attribute_value` instead of `$this->attribute_values` in the foreach loop, it works ?

Comment: Which foreach is throwing errors, `this->attribute_values` or `$avalues`?

Comment: @aynber this->attribute_values is the one giving errors.

Comment: Then you need to figure out why `this->attribute_values` is null instead of an array. You don't show where that's defined.

Comment: @aynber well thats the issues coz that code has been working perfectly, I didnt add the rest of the code because it part of a very long code snippet that would be unnecessary for the question. But thank you I will keep checking where I went wrong.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  `$this->attribute_values` is null.  You haven't shown or told us anything about that variable, how it is set, where it comes from, etc, so there is nothing anyone here can do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wrapped the code in an if statement like this.

```
 if (is_array($this->attribute_values)){
            foreach ($this->attribute_values as $key => $attribute_value) {
                $avalues = explode(",", $attribute_value);
                foreach ($avalues as $avalue) {
                    $attr_value = new AttributeValue();
                    $attr_value->product_attribute_id = $key;
                    $attr_value->value = $avalue;
                    $attr_value->product_id = $product->id;
                    $attr_value->save();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest also to create a mutator for that attribute in the model. 

`public function getAttributesValues(){
        return $this->attribute_values ?: [];
}`

It will return *$this->attribute_values* if has value or an empty array if null.
This way you can use it in a lot of *foreach*'s without using `if` conditional.

P.S: You can also use also `getAttributesValuesArray` as a method name in case you do not want to modify `$this->attribute_values` when called.

Comment: Thanks at @AntonioGocaj will sure implement that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$main_data = new Collection($this->attribute_values);
$main_data = $main_data->toArray();
foreach ($main_data as $key=>$attribute_value) {
    $avalues = explode(",", $attribute_value);
    foreach ($avalues as $avalue) {
        $attr_value = new AttributeValue();
        $attr_value->product_attribute_id = $key;
        $attr_value->value = $avalue;
        //$attr_value->product_id = $product->id;
        $attr_value->save();
    }
}
```